# Google Chrome window.open height includes URL bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

When we open a window using:

```
window.open("/calendar",'calendar','width=950,height=576,titlebar=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
```

Firefox 3 and IE 7 open it to have a content area height of 576 plus the browser items (URL bar, status bar, etc).

Chrome however opens it to have a total height of 576 meaning a scrollbar appears to the right of the content (and then the bottom because the width is now reduced).

How can I get around this?  It's for a heavy layout part of a web app so it's not just a matter of "let the user scroll", the client doesn't want that.

Has anyone come across this?

I don't mind browser sniffing and opening the window bigger, but I know that's yucky these days.

Comment: hope this help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994945/how-to-do-window-open-with-no-scrollbars-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to reliably control the `window.open` function. For example in Opera the pop-up window is always resizeable. And most browsers always show the URL bar for security reasons.

Either do what haim evgi's link suggests and set `overflow:hidden` CSS in the pop-up page, or go for in-page approach, like a lightbox script. You can open external pages in iframes using those and you can control the size exactly. They often look better, too.

Answer (score 1):

I know is stupid but you can sniff chrome and increase the height. This is how i did it..

```
    wh=576;
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Chrome')>0) wh=wh+50;
window.open("/calendar",'calendar','width=950,height='+wh+',titlebar=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var popup = window.open("/calendar",'calendar','width=950,height=576,titlebar=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no');
popup.resizeBy(0, 576 - popup.innerHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change from 'status=no'  to 'status=yes'.