# JavaScript window options

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I'm looking to create a "pop-up" window that simply displays text within the window without the browser's signature. When I create a window simply by using the window.open command, the Chrome symbol and address bar is displayed.

Is there a way to get rid of this?
Or is there a smarter way of doing this?

Also, with that being said, I want this window to stay on top of all other windows being displayed. That is, I want it to essentially be running on top of a window even though I may be clicking on a full screen window behind it.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a modal dialog, something like jqueryui? What you're describing is actively disallowed by most browsers as it provides too many opportunities to spam or otherwise annoy users.

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.open) for how to disable some window features. However, making it "stay on top" is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is intentionally made not possible (at least in Chrome) because it could be used to confuse the user to think that a browser window is a window for another program.

[Google Chrome window.open height includes URL bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048615/google-chrome-window-open-height-includes-url-bar)