# Pop Window's attributes not changing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, popupwindow

I tried the following simple pop-up code obtained from [here](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_popup_window_code.cfm) and slightly modified-

```
<!-- sample.html -->
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=400,width=400,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no')
}
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.facebook.com/zuck');">Open a popup window</a>
```

When I run this, a pop window appears as expected. But the scrollbars and the URL are very much there and I could easily resize the window even though I've `resizable=no,scrollbars=no,location=no`

Why isn't the change to these attributes reflecting in the resultant pop up window?

Strange this is `scrollbar` attribute reflects properly on `Mozilla 10.0.4` and not on `Google Chrome 19.0.1084.56`

But the other 2 attributes show the same behavior on either of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing here is that these settings are *suggestions* to the browser. The browser vendor may choose to have the browser ignore them. Some vendors (including Mozilla) let users define whether certain settings are ignored (see various notes on [MDN's `window.open` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)).

You can avoid scrollbars by styling the resulting document as described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995823/157247) here (provided the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) doesn't come into play), but if the browser is supplying location and resizing when you're telling it not to, there's really nothing else you can do — using a pop-up window.

You might consider instead using an absolutely-positioned element within your current window, which is pretty much the modern way to do popups. Your specific example loading Facebook may require you use an `iframe` (and may try to escape it), though.