# Window.open on chrome

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have a form in a pop-up that will open when the index.php is opened and closes the index.php at the same time. My problem is that when i open the pop-up sometimes it has a scrollbar and sometimes it doesn't but everytime i refresh inside the pop-up the scrollbars disappear because the size for the pop-up is the same size for my form div.

my code for opening the pop-up form

```
var popup = window.open('forms/customersform.php', 'myWindowName', 'left=500,top=200,width=318,height=340','scrollbars=no;');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the scrollbars part inside quotes

```
var popup = window.open('forms/customersform.php', 'myWindowName', 'left=500,top=200,width=318,height=340,scrollbars=no');
```

Someone else had a similar issue: [How to do window.open with no scrollbars in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994945/how-to-do-window-open-with-no-scrollbars-in-google-chrome)

Comment: without semicolon at the last? like scrollbars=no;

Comment: it still has scrollbars. but as i said earlier when i refresh the pop-up the scrollbars disappear, pretty weird.

Comment: Apparently someone else had a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994945/how-to-do-window-open-with-no-scrollbars-in-google-chrome. I've noticed that some browsers disregard the parameters for window.open (in particular the status bar and address bar).

Comment: you should edit your answer to the link you gave in the comment so i can accept it :) @Robbert